# what is the best Firebase alternative for flutter to migrate as fast as possible?

Tags: flutter, backend

We just launched a project that uses Flutter and Firebase services: Auth, Firestore, Functions.
We just find out that Firebase doesn't work on Huawei phones.
Which backend service is the fastest and most reliable to use in Flutter to migrate the entire project?

Comment: We put so much on advertising in china and Middle-east, Politics are just sad. 
I'm losing my job because of this madness, please any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: I suggest AWS Amplify - its in developer preview mode now but is rapidly progressing - also note that the amplify flutter framework is in developer preview only, its still using rock solid AWS services for everything in your backend- I'm currently using it in an app I'm developing and works brilliantly. [link here](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/q/integration/flutter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just migrated an entire project to [Supabase](https://pub.dev/packages/supabase) and it is a great alternative, Also as mentioned in the comments by Ranvir, [AWS Amplify](https://pub.dev/publishers/aws-amplify.com/packages) is another alternative, but needs more work.